# Connecting multiple VF pages

Tags: visualforce, navigation

What I want to do is have a next button on my first page and from there, I would want to navigate to another VF page. Kind of confused on how to do it and at the same time, also save all the data that the variables hold from the first page. I searched it online and I saw a lot of references to Page Reference but I was unsure if that would carry all the data and not make it null. I did try it before and it did that so I had to change my application layout.

Any idea on how I can approach this? Or if a simple example can be shown, that be dope!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have multiple pages that use the same controller extension (a common pattern for creating a series of wizard pages connected via Next/Previous) then the controller values are preserved between pages so you don't have to do anything extra. See e.g. [Creating a Wizard](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm). Your mention of a "Next" button suggests that this may be your situation.

If the pages have separate controller extensions (for example the pages do very different things), then you can pass values in the URL by adding to the parameters collection in the action method invoked by the button or link of the first page:

```
public PageReference() yourMethod() {
    PageReference p = ...;
    p.getParameters().put('x', 'hello');
    p.getParameters().put('y', 'world');
    return p;
}
```

and then in the controller for the second page you can pick the values up like this:

```
    String x = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('x');
    // x will be 'hello'
    String y = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('y');
    // y will be 'world'
```

Pick names that make sense for your code. The values added/extracted will be automatically escaped/unescaped for you keeping the URL syntax valid.

There are length limits on URLs, so limit the amount of data you pass to no more than a few hundred characters; that is usually not a problem. (For example pass an `Id` of an object not a copy of the object itself.)